# mean and median of residuals from a linear model

Tags: r, mean

I just started to learn R and need some help on finding the mean and median of residuals for my data. I calculated the lm and in the summary I get residuals like follows:

```
min       1Q        median  3Q      Max
-111.86   -34.90     -7.6   33.46   182.58
```

**Question**: so the median of residuals is -7.6 but which is my mean?
**Or is there a calculation for finding mean and median of residuals?**
I was going to do mean(resid(trees.lm) or should it be entered as mean(trees.lm$resid)

Please clarify because my classmates all get different responses for the same data set.

Answer (score 7):

The answer to the one specific question here is:

```
mean(resid(trees.lm))
```

You shouldn't delve into fitted model objects like this and strip out arbitrary components. Doing so on something a bit more complicated like a GLM will bite your hand off when you realise you just extracted the working residuals via:

```
glm.mod.obj$residuals
```

which are unlikely to be useful to you.

Even for simple things like `lm()` objects, what using `resid()` or accessing `$residuals` can be different depending upon how the model was fitted (what was the setting for the `na.action` argument for example?).

Also, the linear model assumes that the residuals are i.i.d. Gaussian (or normal) random variables with mean 0 and variance $\hat{\sigma}^2}$ so the mean should be very close to 0 (i.e. very, very, very close to 0 but not exactly because this is a computer and floating point arithmetic is in play).

Comment: Regardless of how the model fits the mean of the residuals will be close to zero. This should never be surprising in OLS.

Comment: Oops, had something else in my mind when I was writing that and you are quite right. Editing out my stupidity.

Comment: In OLS the sum of the residuals is exactly equal to zero.  It is a property of minimizing the squared residuals.

Comment: @MichaelChernick, You're right, except that `R` typically reports a mean of `1e-14` or something similar. That's why I left my comment as "close to zero" rather than "exactly zero".

Comment: Indeed @Max and hence why I left in the close to zero bit when I made my edit. Mathematically it should be 0 but the computer will report it as something almost zero, which might confuse people if they are not aware of this.